# Inconsistent "cannot access file" error when processing flat file

Tags: ssis

We have an SSIS 2008R2 process that includes a step where an external application is launched in a task that executes a remote procedure call.  The external application produces output as a flat file, which SSIS is then supposed to pick up and process.  When the external process has finished, the task that launched it completes successfully.

The executive summary version of our problem is that we seem to always have to run the package twice before the step succeeds that processes the flat file.  Anyone have an idea why, and what we might try to resolve this?

Here are the gory details:

The SSIS package pauses while the external process is running, as it is supposed to do, and waits for the "all clear" from the external application before attempting to read the file that has been produced.  (FWIW, the external application creates the file when it starts, then populates it over the course of its run.)

Our problem is that, both during development when the package is being run from BIDS and during testing when the package is run as a scheduled SQL Server job, the package would *sometimes* (bot not always) fail and report that it was unable to open the text file.  BUT, it is not consistent.

The file in question is written to a network share.  We have verified that the share is accessible to the network account under which the job runs, as well as to the developers.

We have tried adding a script task that does the following:

- Verify that the file exists
- If the file exists, try to open it as a stream for read/write access, in exclusive mode.
- If the file is not available, wait for a specified time and try again.  Keep trying until either it is successfully opened (and then closed again), or until the limit of number of tries is reached.
- Once the file has been successfully opened, close the stream and wait for a few more seconds in case there is a latency problem of some sort.

Although the script is designed to report a failure if it is never able to open the file, we have never seen that branch of the code actually execute (i.e. we are ALWAYS successful in an attempt to open the file).

We know that networks are busy places and that, microseconds after we close the file, something else *could* come along behind our backs and open it again, but there is absolutely no reason to expect this to be the case in our environment.

Finally, when the package is run from the SQL Server job on a schedule it always fails.  When we do nothing more than re-execute the job manually, it seems to "always" succeed.  (It was not always so; before we upped the wait time after our successful attempt to open the file even this was not enough.)

The code that we use to test for whether the flat file could be opened came from a thread right here on StackOverflow.  I'm happy to post it if anyone thinks our test might itself be contributing to the problem, but it's hard to understand how that could be since the package works *sometimes*.

Comment: As a first step to troubleshooting I suggest that you lose all the bits of checking code and just put an extended hard wait, something like 5 minutes. Just start with this as a way to try and get some reliable results. Do you have access to the remote server where the process is run? It would be handy to run some monitoring tools on there (i.e. OPENFILES) to see if a process has the file open. What is the remote process that you are calling? You could add some more steps to that to wait a little bit after completion before returning. Lastly another way to check file access is try and rename it

Answer (score 0):

Lets give a try like following...
Can you create a Proxy under SSIS Package Execution.
Try to execute this step with this proxy(Run As drop down once you edit Step).

Comment: If it is an intermittent issue then I doubt very much that it has anything to do with the run account.